# I seem to be getting an error in Unity regarding the end of 9th line down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    ///rotate character model if stick is tilted right or left, but only if character is moving in that direction.
    if (IsInLocomotion () && ((direction >= 0 && horizontal >= 0) || (direction < 0 && horizontal < 0))) 
    {
        Vector3 rotationAmount = Vector3.Lerp (Vector3.zero, new Vector3 (0f, rotationDegreePerSecond* (horizontal < 0f ? -1f : 1f), 0f), Mathf.Abs);
        Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotationAmount * Time.deltaTime);
        this.transform.rotation = (this.transform.rotation * deltaRotation);
    }

}
```

this one specific part of my code is giving me an error. If anyone would happen to know what exactly is wrong with it it i would be very grateful.

i keep getting the error

> Assets/CharacterControllerLogics.cs(100,58): error CS1502: The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.Vector3.Lerp(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3,
>   float)' has some invalid arguments

and

> Assets/CharacterControllerLogics.cs(100,58): error CS1503: Argument
>   `#3' cannot convert`method group' expression to type `float'

Answer (score 3):

You're passing `Mathf.Abs` (a method) to a method that's expecting a `float` as its third parameter. Perhaps you are supposed to be supplying a value to `Mathf.Abs` (the result of which would be of type `float`)? e.g.:

```
Vector3.Lerp (Vector3.zero, new Vector3 (0f, rotationDegreePerSecond * 
    (horizontal < 0f ? -1f : 1f), 0f), Mathf.Abs(42.0));
                                                ^^^^^^
```

Comment: DAM! thank you so much dude! totally helped me out! i substituted the 42 for 2f and it works now :)))!!! sorry im a noob to this type of stuff x)

Comment: @user3858703: Hey, it's what we're here for! To learn and to teach.  Also, since you're new here, if an answer provided you with a correct solution, make sure to mark it as answered. Cheers!